# why do some pavlova recipes have cream of tarter to be added

Tags: baking

What is the function of cream of tarter when it is included in a pavlova recipe. Some receipes do not require it.

Answer (score 1):

Pavlova is essentially a baked meringue, which is made from egg whites. The purpose of cream of tartar ( tartaric acid ) is to help denature the proteins in the egg whites, making a more stable foam once you whip it and bake it.

Comment: it makes it more stable for whipping ... baking it sets the foam, so likely isn't needed at that point.

Comment: my receipe for pavlova roll has  4 egg whites, I teaspoon vinegar and I teaspoon cornflour in it. Would you suggest adding cream of tarter.  If I doubled the mixture how long would I need to bake it?